# URL pattern for real website

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` to inject script to sites, but I don't want to inject to invalid tabs, such as: chrome://extension, newtab, blank tab etc. Which pattern I can choose in

```
chrome.tabs.query({url:"????"}, function(tabs){

});
```

Can I use `url:"*://*"`? It still match to `chrome://extension`.

Comment: You can specify an array of patterns like `url: ['http://*/*', 'https://*/*']`

Comment: How to exclude `https://chrome.google.com` We cannot inject script to this site.

Comment: Simply check each tab's url in the callback. Also, AFAICT there's no such site, it's redirected to https://www.google.com/chrome/ where you **can** inject content scripts: https://puu.sh/A9vvI/3dce9664b6.png